# Where/how can I inlay my app screenshots to make an iPhone animation for a website?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design

I would like to do something like this: http://www.fixed.com/ It's quite common, but I have not been able to find a site or psd download that allows users to embed screenshots in phones. Does anyone know where a newbie can do this? Thanks for any tips.

Comment: What are you trying to do? The Iphone is just a background image and the slider is [flexslider](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/). Nothing is embed. The images were uploaded by the makers of the site, not users. Unless I am missing something.

Comment: @AndrewH I guess I am wondering where I can get an image of an iphone. I know I could photograph one and all that, but I'm thinking there must be plenty of these online somewhere, maybe even officially provided by Apple?

Comment: Google Iphone stock photo. There are plenty of stock websites that will have one.

Comment: While not exactly the same between @AndrewH suggestion of finding a photo on any number of stock websites, and the question above I think you should be covered. If you have a more specific question feel free to start a new question to ask, but I'm voting to close this in its current form.

Comment: Well that's not entirely true, but I did get my answer. Thanks. I would delete the post but I don't see a delete option.

Comment: If you found a different answer that you think is worth posting it you're welcome to do so either on your own question (think its a 24hr wait before you're allowed) or on the question I linked above, or both.

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy way to do this and a google search didn't pull up any pre-built ones with the iPhone as the frame for the slider that I could find. I'm sure they are out there but it's a pain to search for them.

My method is to grab a mobile phone mockup from a site like [Freebiesbug](http://freebiesbug.com/psd-freebies/mockups-psd-freebies/) and slice it up into a table or DIV layout. Then go get a basic slider, configure it to the right sizing for the window portion of the phone and create your screen shots to fit.